# So confused about this Java Loop

Tags: java, input

I have been trying to get this program to work for ages and every time I try to add a loop that increments the progress counter and refresh the main frame it either just won't display or it will just stay at 0 and every input I enter doesn't affect the program.

```
public class Progress2 
{

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); 

    int progress = 0;
    int prog = 100;
    int count;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command = "";

    public Progress2()
    {


        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 11)); // holds the JLabels in a grid   
        Label label1 = new Label("0%");
        Label label2 = new Label("10%");
        Label label3 = new Label("20%");
        Label label4 = new Label("30%");
        Label label5 = new Label("40%");
        Label label6 = new Label("50%");
        Label label7 = new Label("60%");
        Label label8 = new Label("70%");
        Label label9 = new Label("80%");
        Label label10 = new Label("90%");
        Label label11 = new Label("100%");

        Label label12 = new Label(prog +"%");


        labelPanel.add(label1);
        labelPanel.add(label2);
        labelPanel.add(label3);
        labelPanel.add(label4);
        labelPanel.add(label5);
        labelPanel.add(label6);
        labelPanel.add(label7);
        labelPanel.add(label8);
        labelPanel.add(label9);
        labelPanel.add(label10);
        labelPanel.add(label11);
        labelPanel.add(label12);

        label1.setForeground(Color.green);
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        label3.setForeground(Color.red);
        label4.setForeground(Color.red);
        label5.setForeground(Color.red);
        label6.setForeground(Color.red);
        label7.setForeground(Color.red);
        label8.setForeground(Color.red);
        label9.setForeground(Color.red);
        label10.setForeground(Color.red);
        label11.setForeground(Color.red);

        mainPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);


        if(progress>=1){
            label2.setForeground(Color.green);
        }

        if(progress>=2){
            label3.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=3){
            label4.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=4){
            label5.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=5){
            label6.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=6){
            label7.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=7){
            label8.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=8){
            label9.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=9){
            label10.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=10){
            label10.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        if(progress>=11){
            label11.setForeground(Color.green);
            prog=-10;
        }

        while(true){
            for(count =0; count<11; count++){
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Do you want to increment?");
                String scan = scanner.nextLine();
                progress++;
            }
        }    
    }

    public JComponent getComponent()
    {
            return mainPanel;
    }



    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress");
         frame.getContentPane().add(new Progress2().getComponent());
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
              createAndShowUI();

          }
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: what is this program? the `Scanner` reads a data and doesn't do anything with it? This isn't even a valid application.

Comment: All that your for loop does is increment progress each time the user presses enter.

Comment: how do you break out of while(true)

Comment: It's supposed to increment the progress but the GUI isn't showing. It's supposed to be a small progress application. When the progress increases the labels font changes colour from red too green.

Comment: @Jiddzey You need a break logic for while loop. You could check for user input if it is `y` then increment else if its `n` break the loop.

Comment: @Jiddzey First try using below solution to break while loop. What is happening with your code is class is not finishing its init itself because of never ending `while` loop. Break it and see if it is working.

Comment: Updating the progress variable in that loop does not cause the label foreground color to change because the if statements are only executed once. You need to put those if statements into the loop itself to update what you are seeing. Also, your while loop will never break out. TBH, you do not need the while loop. Only the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are under the impression that every time the progress variable is updated all those if statements will be tested and the GUI will be updated accordingly. This is not the case. Re-write the loop to be as follows and you will see the intended outcome:

```
for(count = 0; count < 11; count++) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Do you want to increment? ");
    String scan = scanner.nextLine();
    progress++;
    if(progress>=1){
        label2.setForeground(Color.green);
    }
    if(progress>=2){
        label3.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=3){
        label4.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=4){
        label5.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=5){
        label6.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=6){
        label7.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=7){
        label8.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=8){
        label9.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=9){
        label10.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=10){
        label10.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
    if(progress>=11){
        label11.setForeground(Color.green);
        prog=-10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got to learn somewhere right? On a side can you explain why the GUI doesn't appear till I press enter eleven times?

Comment: The reason has to deal with how to code executes. When this program starts, it starts in the `main` static method. The main static method tells the compiler to run the `createAndShowUI()` method. That method runs your loop first, then displays the GUI after the fact when it runs `frame.setVisible(true)`. Honestly, from what I can tell from what you are asking, you are trying too hard for one of your first programs. Until you understand how the execute flows in a java program, changing how the GUI looks shouldn't even be on your plate.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below flow:

1. `Progress2()` class initialize panels and labels and add on component in `constructor`. That is till `mainPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);`
2. Create a function `updateUI()`
   function void updateUI()
   {
           \Get Panel
           \Get labels from panel
           \`for` loop in that function as mentioned by blahfunk above.
   }

**Learning point here:** How to get panel and labels from that panel. To make it easier check if you can declare panel and labels as class attributes for `Progress2()` class and then you could define class methods to return those values (getters)

3. Call `updateUI()` function after `createAndShowUI();` in `main()` function.

**Why the GUI doesn't appear till I press enter eleven times?**

This is where code for update is called. `frame.getContentPane().add(new Progress2().getComponent());` inside `new Progress2()` That is constructor for class `Progress2()`
`frame.setVisible(true);` is responsible to show UI which is called after above statement.

To see your code in action follow the above workflow for code that should do.